# Set css style on DataListItem render as Td element of table

Tags: asp.net

I use clasic asp.net 4.0. I have big problem with set at DataListItem element css style. This item are render as td so I think that it will be easy, but is not :/

U use code like:

```
<%# (((DataListItem)Container).Styles["border-color"] = "Red")==""?"":"" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that it's easy solution:
use that code :

```
<ItemStyle BorderWidth="0px" />
```